# Make whole django project installable including apps

Tags: python, django, setuptools

We have microservice architecture and each Django project acts as a small microservice.
every Django project has at least one app running, we are trying to make our Django project installable so we can ship these microservices anywhere.

I am able to make my Django service as installable but when I am adding app path in INSTALLED_APPS it's not allowing it.

My project structure is like 
[image]

`project` directory contains `settings`, `urls` etc files

setup file looks like

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="project",  # Replace with your own username
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Example Author",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",
    long_description="this is test",
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
    project_urls={"Bug Tracker": "https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/issues",},
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="src"),
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    entry_points={
        "mysite.plugin.1": [],
        "console_scripts": ["manage-framework=mysite.manage:main"],
    },
)
```

now when I install this and try to run a server with `manage-framework runserver` its throwing below error.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'polls'. Check that 'mysite.polls.apps.PollsConfig.name' is correct.
```

I have added `mysite.polls.apps.PollsConfig` in INSTALLED_APPS

Note: I am following the packaging structure from here [Packaging](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

Comment: And `python -c "import mysite.polls.apps"` works? Maybe you're missing an `__init__.py` in `src/mysite/polls`?